# What is the reason for compensation at async generator outputs?

Tags: generator

I see capacitor banks are installed at async generator outputs. What is the function of compensation in this case? I thought compensation was done at the consumer and for induction motors.

Can this be explained by using phasors and reactive and active power concepts?

Answer (score 0):

If the generator is grid connected, the grid operator may require capacitor banks so that the generator can operate without depending on the grid to supply the magnetizing current that it requires. In addition, the grid operator may require the installation to supply reactive current to supply inductive loads connected to the grid.

An induction generator's magnetizing current is an inductive reactive power load on the grid. Only wound-field synchronous generators and capacitors can supply reactive power to inductive loads.

If the generator is not grid connected, it can not operate with out a capacitor bank to supply its magnetizing current.

Comment: Im asking the reason behind i.e what really happens.

Comment: @panic_attack: See my revised answer.